# Javascript/Html/CSS TransformToggle and slideToggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I'm coding a website and got a problem. I want to use an img as a link to slideToggle a content. This is happening but I want the img to rotate 90deg on the first click and -90deg on the second one.
Hope you're have a solution. <3

this is my code:

```js
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.button_img').click(function() {

      $('div.show_more_content').slideToggle(300);
      $(this).children('img.button_img').toggleClass(".button_img").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";

    });

  });
</script>
```

```html
<div id="more">
  <section id="show_more">

    <div id="show_more_button"><img src="img/cross.png" class="button_img" id="button_img" height="100px" width="100px" />
    </div>
  </section>
  <div id="show_more_content" class="show_more_content">
    <ul>
      <li>Welcome</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=Javascript%2FHtml%2FCSS%20TransformToggle%20and%20slidetoggle

Answer (score 0):

Just add this css

```
.button_img.active{
     -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
     transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

replace this line from your js

```
$(this).children('img.button_img').toggleClass(".button_img").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```

with

```
$(this).toggleClass("active");
```

If you want transition effect then please add below style in your button css

```
.button_img{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s;
    -ms-transition: all 1s
    -o-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```